# Signature using RSA (as described in Cryptography engineering)

Tags: rsa, signature

In the book *"Cryptography engineering"* (2010, Ferguson), I found, page 209/210, these 3 functions: `MsgToRSANumber`, `SignWithRSA`, `VerifyRSASignature` (see below).

I can't understand how the last function `VerifyRSASignature` works. It seems that it checks if "the given signature $\sigma$ raised to exponent $e$ mod $n$" (this part is ok) **is equal to $s$, which is the result of `MsgToRSANumber`, i.e. the result of a random choice!**

How can this work? **Isn't there a mistake here?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pseudocode shown is correct.

It works because $\mathsf{MsgToRSANumber}$ is a function in the mathematical sense; and in particular, always returns the same result for the same arguments $(n,m)$. This is possible because it internally uses a [Pseudo Random Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (PRNG), rather than a True RNG (which indeed would make the signature verification fail).

The rationale for using a (P)RNG to transform the message $m$ into the message representative $s$ is that the (conjecturally hard) RSA problem is to invert the public key function $s\to s^e\bmod n$ for a ***random*** $s$ in interval $[0,n)$. If we used $s=m$, or a simple transformations (e.g. $s\ =\ (a\;m+b)\bmod n$ for some public constants $a$, $b$ ), an attack would often be tractable. The signature system proposed has some level of reducibility to the RSA problem.

This signature scheme is known as Full Domain Hash. See [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89847/555) for references.

[RSASSA-PSS](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=27) of PKCS#1v2, and RSA per [ISO/IEC 9796-2](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:9796:-2:ed-3:v1:en) scheme 2, are signature systems which combine a PRNG and a TRNG in preparing the message representative $s$. The TRNG insures that an adversary can not predict or choose which $s$ the legitimate signer will use, even if given the opportunity to choose the messages signed. This allows stronger/simpler security reduction.

Comment: Thank you very much @fgrieu. Ok so `MsgToRSANumber` always returns the same result for the same arguments, because the PRNG **only** uses SHA(m) as seed, and **no other source of entropy**? Is that correct? [I was thinking the PRNG uses this seed, but also other sources of entropy, and that was my misunderstanding... how would it be called in this case? Not a PRNG, would this be a TRNG?]

Comment: @Basj: you are correct about why `MsgToRSANumber`always returns the same result for the same arguments. A PRNG that's fed true entropy, even partially, is no longer a PRNG. It remains an RNG, and arguably becomes a TRNG; but the definition of the later is ambiguous (some use True as meaning _straight from an entropy source_), thus I would call what you describe a TRNG mixing seed and entropy with some post-conditioning, or just a RNG.