# Security of Full Domain Hash (or not quite full)

Tags: rsa, signature, provable-security, random-oracle-model, trapdoor

*Full Domain Hash* is the simplest signature scheme based on a trapdoor permutation (such as textbook RSA) that enjoys a strict security reduction. It was introduced by Mihir Bellare and Phillip Rogaway: [*The Exact Security of Digital Signatures - How to Sign with RSA and Rabin*](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/exact.pdf#page=8) (in [proceedings of EuroCrypt 1996](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-68339-9_34)).

Bellare and Rogaway's security bound was improved by Jean-Sébastien Coron: [*On the Exact Security of Full Domain Hash*](http://www.crypto-uni.lu/jscoron/publications/fdh.pdf) (in [proceedings of Crypto 2000](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44598-6_14)) and [*Optimal Security Proofs for PSS and Other Signature Schemes*](http://www.crypto-uni.lu/jscoron/publications/optimal.pdf#page=8) (in [proceedings of EuroCrypt 2002](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-46035-7_18)).

I first ask a *didactic* exposition of the security proof of FDH. Preferably, the improved one.

**If possible:** does that allow to quantify the security loss when the hash is not quite full-domain, but rather is uniformly distributed on a proportion $\alpha\in(0,1)$ of the RSA domain? E.g. if the hash is uniformly distributed on $h\lesssim\log_2N$ bits, we have $\alpha=2^h/N$ .

Update: FDH is also analyzed in Dan Boneh and Victor Shoup's [*A Graduate Course in Applied Cryptography*](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/cryptobook/BonehShoup_0_6.pdf#section.13.3).